# How to get rid of "null" node in payload (fulfillment response)?

Tags: node.js, dialogflow-es

I'm using `dialogflow-fulfillment` for fulfillment. I am trying to send a payload using the following function;

```
function getName(agent) {
        let options = {
          "options": [
                {
                    "id": "make_reservation",
                    "text": "Reservations",
                    "payload": "make_reservation"
                  }
            ]
        };

        let newPayload = new Payload('PLATFORM_UNSPECIFIED', options);
        agent.add('added by webhook');
        agent.add(newPayload);
}
```

But I'm getting a `null` node in the fulfillment response.

```
{
  "payload": {
    "null": {
      "options": [
        {
          "id": "make_reservation",
          "text": "Reservations",
          "payload": "make_reservation"
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "outputContexts": []
}
```

In the place of the  `null` node, I need the `options` node. Any idea how to do that?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing some more search, I got the answer! `Payload` takes three parameters.

`new Payload(platform, payload, options);`

where the default options are `{sendAsMessage: false, rawPayload: false}`. Since `rawPayload` is `false`, payload will be nested on the `platform` name. In my case `platform` was `PLATFORM_UNSPECIFIED`, that's why it was nested on a `null` node.

So the solution is to set `rawPayload` to `true`.

```
let newPayload = new Payload('PLATFORM_UNSPECIFIED', options, {rawPayload: true});
```